# What does this diagram mean, in English?

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to figure out what this means, particularly regarding how to treat the red and black wires coming out of the switch.

The switch box I have has red, black, green, and white wires.  The part of this diagram that confuses me is the line with "switch/black <- switch/red".  What does this mean?[image]

Comment: Can you link the diagram?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You would get more answers if you would be so kind and turn the picture around so that everybody can just read it

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate text labels there, which apply to 2 separate wires.

One of the labels is "switch/black" which seems wrong. It seems like it ought to be describing the switched-hot wire going up to the fan, and black is at best a guess which color it might be; red is likely.   The other label is "switch/red" which seems right.

The symbol is not part of the text labels, it is part of the diagram.  It  is meant to be a wire nut.

The labeling and instructions are part of the UL approval which results in a UL listing, and it's a surprise to see such an amateurish mistake.  **Are you *sure* this thing is actually UL-listed** (or CSA, ETL or other comparable NRTL; note that CE is not one). There is a lot of cheap Cheese junk being offered on Amazon Marketplace, eBay, banggood and other purveyors of the junk from Alibaba; most of this has the ill-reputed CE mark if it has any markings at all.  **These cannot be attached to mains wires in the US or Canada**, NEC 110.2 "Equipment must be approved" (by UL or other NRTL).

Comment: This is from a HomeNetWerks fan/light/speaker combo from Home Depot.  These seem to cause much confusion, there are a number of YouTube vids out there that try to explain how to install, but it's still pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The power wire coming from the house likely has black (hot), white (neutral), and green or bare (ground). According to the diagram, the fan has a black wire (switched hot in), white (neutral), and green (ground). The switch has corresponding black (hot in), red (switched hot out), white (neutral), and green (ground).

You'll hook all the green/bare grounds wires together. Hook all the white neutrals together. The black hot from the house goes to the black hot in on the switch. The red switched hot goes out from the switch to the black hot in on the fan. If you're still unsure about the wiring please consult an electrician.

I'm surprised by the comment "Do not use metal wall plate...", particularly since the HD website shows this fan as "1-UL Listed, HVI Certified, cUL Listed". I presume not using a metal plate in a potentially wet situation is to avoid a shock risk. If the switch is properly designed, I would think the switch mounting tabs and cover plate would be grounded. Do the instructions say any more about this?